# How can I find the phpmyadmin SQL password encryption type?

Tags: mysql, password-encryption

I am very sorry if this has been answered before, but I have searched for 2 days and cannot find the answer.  I have 2 databases and I need to import users from the current database to a new one.  The new database is for a chat system that has recently bee installed and I would like all users to be added to it.

So I thought I would simply manually add the users in the new database using information from phpmyadmin.  But the encryption for the password is a different format and will not work.

For example in the first database the encryption is:
z70I9QINffX2Hh7FxQ==

In the second database the format is:
3eb5c61f784aa3c2e11d879382387d420f7c4ebf

Neither seem to be MD5 and I can't find out which type it is.

I know this is a stretch but does anyone know of a way to detect the type of encryption and how I can take a password, such as 'password' and encrypt it using the correct encryption type?

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about application level user accounts here, or MySQL user accounts (the latter ones are stored in the `mysql` database). Also, passwords are usually not encrypted, but are hashed. Hashes are not reversible.

Comment: Thank you.  I am referring to MySQL user accounts (Hashed).  If I copy a password from database 1 to database 2 is will not work, because it appears that database 2 has a different hash.  Both databases are on the same server.

Comment: If both databases are on the same server, then these are application level user accounts, not mysql ones, since a single mysql server has a single user table. There is nothing to copy. You may have multiple mysql servers (instances) on the same host. Is this the case? If this is the case, what's the version of the newer mysql instance?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a generic password for the root user, or logging into mysql as the root user & creating another user manually. Not sure what kind of access you have, but that's been the best bet in my experience.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The password encryption mechanism would be stored in the application's code. The 1st example looks like Base64 but can't be sure without comparing others. The 2nd example appears to be SHA1/MySQL5 Sha1(Sha1(pass)).

You're going to have to research the apps that are using these databases and to determine how it's creating and storing these account passwords in the database. Either way, you are trying to link 2-dbs that have different password mechanisms, that might require standardization of the passwords which might mean a password resets.

There is a harder way, you have a database of one-way hashed passwords. It will require a bit of focus in scripting... You would have to generate hashes for the cryptographic hashes used and compare to your users passwords to get the plaintext password. Then you recreate their accounts in the new DB using their passwords to create the new user with same credentials.